# Complex no maximization

Tags: complex-numbers

If $$|z_1|=2,|z_2|=3,|z_3|=4$$

Find the maximum value of 
$|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_3-z_2|^2+|z_1-z_3|^2$

I tried using its geometrical interpretation but didn't get the answer.Try give an answer using geometrical aproach, algebraic would also do.

Comment: Please show us what you did, so we can see where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is small enough to check all (8) possible variations and to select the maximum.

Here is a small python program which does that (so this is not an algebraic or geometric, but rather programmatic approach):

```
from itertools import product
l = [2, 3, 4]
m = - 1
for i in product([1, -1], repeat=3):
    a, b, c = [a * b for a, b in zip(l, i)]
    tmp = abs(a - b)**2 + abs(b - c)**2 + abs(c - a)**2
    if tmp > m:
        m = tmp
        ans = a, b, c

print m, ans
```

And it tells you that maximum value is 86 and one of the ways to achieve it is `(2, 3, -4)`.